# rearrange the buttons in layout when one is hidden

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

I am working on an application . It uses a main layout..

In it I use a relative layout and i have 4 buttons .

Button 1 , Button 2, Button 3 and Button 4

So based on user credentials and capabilities, i hide some buttons. e.g

Admin can view all the buttons

Button 2 and 3 is hidden for user account .So when user login, i show only Button 1 and Button 4.

But i want to rearrange the UI look.

Currently, when Button 2 and 3 are hidden , there is a big space between button 1 and 4 , when viewing on the screen.

When Button 2 and 3 are hidden, i want to move Button 1 at the place of Button 3 (nearer to 4 on the UI ) . so that it looks good on viewing the screen.

I dont know how to achieve this. Please let me know how to rearrange the buttons in the layout when one button is hidden

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Info_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Camera_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/division_LinearLayout"
            android:background="@drawable/camera_selector" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Favorite_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/GotoCamera_Button"
            android:background="@drawable/favorite_btn_selector" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Profile_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Favorite_Button"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_list_btn_selector" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Info_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ProfileList_Button"
            android:background="@drawable/camerainfo_selector" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try `btn.setVisibility=View.GONE` in your activity

Answer (score 3):

Try using setVisibility(View.GONE) on your buttons instead of just making them invisible. When they're gone, they don't take up space for layout purposes, unlike when they are just INVISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the buttons like this :

```
   ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) btnToRemove.getParent();
   if(null!=layout) layout.removeView(btnToRemove);
```